# C# Telegram Bot API Отправить несколько аудио

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Такая проблема, нужно оправить несколько аудиофайлов в канал.

Успешно отправляю 1 файл:

```
 Message messages = await botClient.SendAudioAsync(
                                    chatId: Channel,
                                    audio: AudioURL
                                );
```

**AudioURL** - ссылка на аудиофайл (загружен на стороннем сайте)

Файл отправляется, пробую отправить несколько аудиофайлов:

```
 var Audio = post.Audio.Select(x => new InputMediaAudio(x)).ToList();

  Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                                    chatId: Channel,
                                    inputMedia: Audio
                                );
```

**post.Audio** - List< string > - список ссылок на аудиофайлы  (загруженые на стороннем сайте)

Получаю ошибку:

> не удается преобразовать из
> "System.Collections.Generic.List<Telegram.Bot.Types.InputMediaAudio>"
> в
> "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Telegram.Bot.Types.IAlbumInputMedia>".

Пытаюсь указать тип явно:

```
 Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                                    chatId: Channel,
                                    inputMedia: (IEnumerable<IAlbumInputMedia>)Audio
                                );
```

Компилятор перестает ругаться, но при выполнении получаю ошибку:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Telegram.Bot.Types.InputMediaAudio]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Telegram.Bot.Types.IAlbumInputMedia]'.

Точно так же отправляю список фото или видео файлов и ошибок нет:

```
var videos = Video.Select(x => new InputMediaVideo(x)).ToList();

 Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                                  chatId: Channel,
                                  inputMedia: videos
                              );
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Спасибо

Comment: https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot/tree/master/src/Telegram.Bot/Types/InputFiles `IAlbumInputMedia` наследуют только классы `InputMediaVideo` и `InputMediaPhoto`. Получается, что никак не отправить аудиофайлы пачкой. Читайте исходники на гитхабе, они вам ответят на большинство вопросов.

Comment: @aepot, https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup  Array of InputMediaAudio, InputMediaDocument, InputMediaPhoto and InputMediaVideo

Comment: @aepot, https://core.telegram.org/bots/api-changelog  Added support for sending and receiving audio and document albums in the method sendMediaGroup.